# Adding DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - when grid refreshed index of column changes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm getting some weird behavior with adding a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a DataGridView. Here is my code:

```
        private void CreateSupplyTypeColumn()
        {
            supplyTypeCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            supplyTypeCombo.HeaderText = "Circuit Type";
            supplyTypeCombo.Name = "colCircuitType";
            supplyTypeCombo.DataSource = supplyType;
            supplyTypeCombo.DisplayMember = "SupplyTypeShort";
            supplyTypeCombo.ValueMember = "SupplyTypeID";
            dgDeliveryPoints.Columns.Insert(4, supplyTypeCombo);
        }

        private void btnSearch1_ByIsCurrent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgDeliveryPoints.DataSource = null
            dgDeliveryPoints.DataSource = dpResult;
            if (!dgDeliveryPoints.Columns.Contains(supplyTypeCombo))
                 CreateSupplyTypeColumn();
            else
                 supplyTypeCombo.DisplayIndex = 4;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgDeliveryPoints.Rows)
                row.Cells[4].Value = row.Cells["SupplyTypeID"].Value;

}
```

The first time I press the search button the btnSearch1_ByIsCurrent method triggers and the supplyTypeCombo looks good. it's properly positioned in the dgDeliveryPoints grid and it has the proper values but I get strange behavior when I press the search button again.
When I press the button again the index of the supplyTypeCombo column changes from 4 to 3??Why is this happening? Also, the reason I have this code:

```
        if (!dgDeliveryPoints.Columns.Contains(supplyTypeCombo))
            CreateSupplyTypeColumn();
        else
            supplyTypeCombo.DisplayIndex = 4;
```

Is because even though I null out the datasource to dgDeliveryPoints with each button click to re-set everything and try to add the supplyTypeCombo column back I get an exception stating it's already there. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this line of code:

```
row.Cells[4].Value = row.Cells["SupplyTypeID"].Value;
```

to this:

```
supplyTypeCombo.DataPropertyName = "SupplyTypeID";
```